printing speed 22.04
I have native Postscript network printers on wired Ethernet, all with static IP, all described in CUPS through the socket://9100 interface.  In 18.04  (ghostscript 9.26)  printing a PDF file starts almost instantly, even on longer files.
Immediately on installing 22.04 (gs 9.55) printing now takes minutes to tens of minutes to even start sending to the printer.  Other local hosts on this network, still using 18.04, remain as fast as ever.
Does anyone have any clue what might have caused such a major regression in printing speed? Nothing about the hardware or install or printers was changed--22.04 was a clean install where 18.04 had been.  Even the .ppd files being used are identical
I believe it to be a ghostscript problem, but I am unclear exactly how CUPS printer definitions call ghostscript filters and modules.  I assume, for instance, that ps2write is being called, but don't know how to verify.
One possible approach would be downgrading to the 18.04 version of gs, but I wanted to ask for thoughts before mucking around and breaking some dependency.

The hardware did not change.  Only from 18.04 to 22.04.  However, to answer the question this machine is a file server/workstation with 48GB of RAM on a quad-core Xeon, It is not even close to ever needing swap under any loading.  On 18.04, even my old 2 GB core Duo prints documents nearly immediately.

You can time different versions of Ghostscript using this command line:
time /path/to/gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -o /dev/null SOURCE.PDF There should be no major performance differences between these versions. At least I cannot reproduce them on locally compiled gs.
